# Can't show due to ambiguous type while using Data.Reflection in Haskell

Tags: haskell, reflection, types, algebra, reification

I'm very new to Haskell and am trying to create a type that will represent any instance of Integral over some modulus. I found [some example code online](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.cafe/101430) and am working with that, so my type definition looks like this:

```
data Zn n a = Zn !a !a
```

Most things are working as I'd like; I can show, add, subtract, etc.

```
instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (Zn n a) where
   show (Zn n x) = printf "(%s mod %s)" (show (mod x n)) (show n)

instance (Integral a, Reifies n a) => Num (Zn n a) where
  Zn n x + Zn _ y = Zn n (mod (x + y) n)
  Zn n x - Zn _ y = Zn n (mod (x - y) n)
  Zn n x * Zn _ y = Zn n (mod (x * y) n)
  negate (Zn n x) = Zn n (n - x)
  abs = id
  signum x@(Zn _ 0) = x
  signum (Zn n _) = Zn n 1
  fromInteger x = Zn n (mod (fromInteger x) n)
    where n = reflect (Proxy :: Proxy n)


znToIntegral :: Integral a => Zn n a -> a
znToIntegral (Zn n x) = fromIntegral x
```

However, I can't show the results of arithmetic operations on these types. For example, in GHCi:

```
*Main> let x = Zn 5 3
*Main> x
(3 mod 5)
*Main> let y = Zn 5 7
(2 mod 5)
*Main> let z = x + y
*Main> z
<interactive>:6:1:
    No instance for (Integral a0) arising from a use of ‘print’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Integral GHC.Int.Int16 -- Defined in ‘GHC.Int’
      instance Integral GHC.Int.Int32 -- Defined in ‘GHC.Int’
      instance Integral GHC.Int.Int64 -- Defined in ‘GHC.Int’
      ...plus 9 others
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I've found this issue has come up in a number of other ways that I've tried to implement these numbers, and understanding how the Data.Reflection package works is giving me some troubles. I'd also be curious about any other implementations that seem more natural to others. I had originally tried doing something like

```
newtype Zn n a = Zn a
```

and switched because I thought that it would simplify things, which it hasn't in particular. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular example, `Zn` is an internal implementation detail and it shouldn't be used for constructing numbers. Ideally, `Zn` shouldn't be even exported from a library. Instead, we're supposed to construct using `fromInteger` and numeric literals.

The modulus is introduced in `fromInteger` by reflection, and we only store it in `Zn` to avoid further use of `reflect`, for performance reasons (although I believe `reflect` doesn't have much overhead by default, so we might not gain much by this scheme). If we only use `fromInteger` to create new `Zn`-s, the moduli will be uniform over the whole computation with the `Reifies` constraint. On the other hand, if we manually plug in the modulus into `Zn`, then that piece of `Zn` will always have that modulus, and `reify` (the way by which we supply implicit configuration) won't affect it at all. In other words, it messes up our supposed invariant.

Example use:

```
foo :: (Integral a, Reifies s a) => Zn s a -> Zn s a -> Zn s a
foo a b = e where
  c = 123
  d = a * b - 3
  e = negate (d + c)

showAFooResult = reify 12 (\(Proxy :: Proxy s) -> show (foo 3 4 :: Zn s Int))
-- fooResult == "(0 mod 12)"
```

Inside the body of `foo` everything will have `12` as modulus after we plugged it in using `reify`.

If we squint a bit, `foo` is just a function that expects an extra `Integral` argument which it uses internally as modulus. We can use `reify` to supply the argument, using the the `s` index in `Proxy`.

If we don't supply any value to plug in the `Reifies` hole, then we can't pull out a value. And of course we can't print it, much like we can't print a function.

We can print `Zn 5 5` because it has type `Num a => Zn n a`, so we have no    hole to fill. On the other hand, `Zn 5 5 + Zn 5 5` has type `(Integral a, Reifies n a) => Zn n a`, because we specified the `Reifies n a` constraint in the `Num` instance, and of course the use of `+` demands a `Num` instance. Here we must use `reify` (or some other helper function that calls it) to pull out a result.

Answer (score 2):

For comparison, here's an implementation that doesn't store the modulus and always uses `reflect`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Data.Reflection
import Data.Proxy
import Text.Printf

newtype Zn a s = Zn { getZ :: a }

instance (Integral a, Show a, Reifies s a) => Show (Zn a s) where
       show x = 
           let 
               p = reflect (Proxy::Proxy s)           
           in
               printf "(%s mod %s)" (show (mod (getZ x) p)) (show p)

instance (Integral a, Reifies s a) => Num (Zn a s) where
      Zn x + Zn y = Zn (mod (x + y) (reflect (Proxy::Proxy s)))
      Zn x - Zn y = Zn (mod (x - y) (reflect (Proxy::Proxy s)))
      Zn x * Zn y = Zn (mod (x * y) (reflect (Proxy::Proxy s)))
      negate (Zn x) = Zn ((reflect (Proxy::Proxy s)) - x)
      abs = id
      signum x@(Zn 0) = x
      signum _ = Zn 1
      fromInteger x = Zn (mod (fromInteger x) p)
            where p = reflect (Proxy :: Proxy s)
```

Some auxiliary functions:

```
znToIntegral :: Integral a => Zn a s -> a
znToIntegral (Zn x) = fromIntegral x

-- Convince the compiler that the phantom type in the proxy
-- is the same as the one in the Zn
likeProxy :: Proxy s -> Zn a s -> Zn a s
likeProxy _ = id

withZn :: Integral a => a -> (forall s. Reifies s a => Zn a s) -> a
withZn p z = reify p $ \proxy -> znToIntegral . likeProxy proxy $ z
```

An example of use:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ withZn (7::Int) (Zn 3 + Zn 5)
```

`withZn` works also from ghci.